# How to exclude multiple line patterns using diff?

Tags: regex, unix, diff

I want to do a diff over two xml files but ignore 2-3 line patterns.

eg: Say I want to ignore availability & price while comparing the xml format below.

Here is what I have so far:

```
diff -I '^<PRICE>*' 1.xml 2.xml

<CATALOG>

    <PLANT>  
    <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>  
    <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>  
    <ZONE>4</ZONE>  
    <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>  
    <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>  
    <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>  
    </PLANT>  
</CATALOG>
```

Using the above diff, it skips the price but how do I add availability to this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the files through `grep -v` to remove the lines you don't need and then `diff` them as shown below:

```
diff <(grep -vE "^(<PRICE>|<AVAILABILITY>)" 1.xml) <(grep -vE "^(<PRICE>|<AVAILABILITY>)" 2.xml)
```

`<(...)` syntax is called [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). If your shell does not support it, you will have to use temporary files, like this:

```
$ grep -vE "^(<PRICE>|<AVAILABILITY>)" 1.xml > 1.new.xml
$ grep -vE "^(<PRICE>|<AVAILABILITY>)" 2.xml > 2.new.xml
$ diff 1.new.xml 2.new.xml
```

I don't think `diff -I` can be used with multiple patterns.

Comment: I'll check this out. In the meantime the above diff seemed to work fine between content changes also. Different prices were being ignored.

Comment: Getting "Missing name for redirect."

Comment: oh, I must have an old version of diff.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try using -I again?

This works for me:

```
diff -I 'PRICE' -I 'AVAILABILITY' 1.xml 2.xml
```

Comment: Be careful: if a file has 2 diffs and you only exclude 1 of those 2 patterns with -I, then the diff output will show BOTH diffs and not just the one that you didn't ask it to exclude. This might make it look like -I is not working, even though it is.