# Using diff to ignore lines with certain patterns

Tags: regex, diff

I have two files with certain strings that I want to ignore when I do a diff.

Here is an example:

```
#### ide:0:0:<!echo "Running commands on server instance name: Tower"
Running commands on instance name: Tower0-0-1:5051
........
#### ide:0:0:<svl>

#### ide:0:0:<!echo "Running commands on server name: Power"
Running commands on instance name: Power0-0-1:5051
........
#### ide:0:0:<svl>
```

I want to write a Bash diff command that will ignore lines with patterns (or strings) such as 'Power' and '5051'. How can I write this?

I tried

```
diff -I "*.5051.*" o1.txt o2.txt
```

Comment: Not quite, the or condition did not work. This has worked for: diff -I ".*5051.*. But not trying to exclude two patterns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude multiple line patterns using diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497658/how-to-exclude-multiple-line-patterns-using-diff)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. I did  find that answer and I believe commented there as well.